# No route to host after changing interface to static ip

Tags: linux, dhcp, local-area-network, tcpip, dhcp-server

I installed a Linux (Ubuntu) server inside my home LAN, initially it's automatically configured to use DHCP interface. I'm connecting to this server from another computer using that server's hostname. All OK, my router is configured to use DHCP inside my home network and gives an IPs automatically to each computer. But when I connect to this host using SSH, it warns me that I should accept a fingerprint from each newly assigned IP of the server, and it's a little annoying. So I configured it to use a static IP addressing editing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file like this:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0 iface eth0 inet static

address 192.168.1.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

All works well except that I can't connect to this server using it's hostname. When pinging I see that it's routed to the last assigned IP address that was given by DHCP dynamically, and of course `Destination Host is Unreachable`. I know that I can hardcode it in my `/etc/hosts` file, but I want to know -- why it works well with DHCP and it doesn't with static. Apparently, I don't understand something. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your router is probably acting as a DNS server for the local network handing out information about hosts that received an address via DHCP.  Or to put it differently, when a DHCP request is handled out, the router dynamically updates the local DNS database.  DNSMasq, is a common DHCP+DNS server on routers that does this.

By setting a static address, you are basically robbing your router of the information it needs to respond to DNS queries about your host.

If possible you should set a DHCP reservation in your router, not set a static address.  If that isn't an option, then you simply are going to need to update your hosts files on all your machines, or run a local DNS server.

Comment: Thank you @Zoredache! I've discovered my router configs, and found manual IP reservation, that works :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't connect to the server via the hostname because you haven't statically set any DNS servers. These servers are normally provided to clients when they obtain an address via DHCP, so as it stands you have no mechanism to resolve IP addresses to names. Your DNS server will also need to be aware of the hostname and IP address

You'll need to provide an internal DNS server in your `/etc/resolv.conf` file in a format similar to this

```
nameserver 192.168.1.1
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: I tried to do this, added a line `dns-nameservers 192.168.1.1 8.8.8.8` in my interfaces file, than restart everything possible, but unfortunately nothing happened. The server is still `ping`able by `192.168.1.101`, but not by hostname `localserver` :(

Comment: `cat /etc/resolv.conf` now outputs nameservers as need, but...

Comment: Different distro's have different networking files. Ensure you're putting the DNS servers in the correct files.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about DHCP but most probably about DNS. You have to have an address in `/etc/resolv.conf` where the hostname of your server is known so the resolution can work. I think the DHCP offer inserted something here that is missing (or different) when you are assigning the static ip.

Also, the file `/etc/nsswitch.conf` defines in which order your hosts file, mdns, DNS and such are tried. It's the line beginning with "hosts".

So find out how the resolution of the hostname to its IP address worked in first place (with dhcp) and continue to look on the machine that is mentioned in /etc/resolv.conf or the answering entity in /etc/nsswitch.conf.

Comment: I'm changed nothing neither the client machine, nor the gateway router, just on the server machine that is serves as a web-server for testing purposes. I tried to hardcode `dns-nameservers` as I mentioned earlier in comments, but it's still unreachable :(

Comment: As strange as it might sound, the server is not at all involved in the resolution of its address accross the network. See Zoredaches answer. Use DHCP reservation in your router and set the router as DNS server on your client or, if you want to use the static IP, update all host files.